# Wait pool representation in a java object

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I heard that using `synchronized` keyword to an object creates a wait pool  which stores waiting threads associated the object. How is it represented in the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the Java documentation about [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

> Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention,
>   a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's
>   fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing
>   them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A
>   thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has
>   acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns an
>   intrinsic lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. The other
>   thread will block when it attempts to acquire the lock.

[image]

and also this:

[image]